# Swift Can't play audio on simulator using avaudioplayer

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer, mach-o

I have been trying to play audio on an iOS simulator using Swift in Xcode but all I get is the error below. What is causing this problem?

```
2018-11-08 21:30:14.752040-0800 [9055:150546] Error loading /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClnt.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClnt:  dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClnt.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClnt, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find: /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClnt.plugin/Contents/MacOS/NRDAudioClnt: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
2018-11-08 21:30:14.752328-0800 [9055:150546] Cannot find function pointer NRDACLN_New_Instance for factory <CFUUID 0x600002b8d660> 3E9FAD07-70A8-4980-B39B-BB8B905C9872 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7fe6d950d740 </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/NRDAudioClnt.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

This is the error that I get when running the code below.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "beat3", withExtension: "wav")

do {
    try openingAudioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
    openingAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    openingAudioPlayer.play()
} catch let error {
}
```

Comment: Did you import AVFoundation at the top?

Comment: Yes I imported AVFoundation at the top